# Unable to detect an adb device on USB3.0

Tags: 12.04, usb, adb

When connecting a device using a USB2.0 cable, adb connects to the device properly.
When connecting the same device using a USB3.0 cable, adb doesn't detect the device.

What I notice (using a LeCroy analyzer) is that after setting the USB configuration, the relevant (IMO) difference is that there is no request for the string descriptor that has the adb device ID.

Below is the descriptor that is read for USB2.0 but not for USB3.0

```
Transfer(10) H(S) Control(GET) ADDR(16) ENDP(0) 
_______| bRequest(GET_DESCRIPTOR) wValue(STRING type, Index 3) 
_______| wIndex(Language ID 0x0409) Descriptors(e736c55eec1a) 
_______| Time Stamp(5 . 923 353 566)
```

In addition, the /tmp/adb.log shows

```
find_usb_device():endpoints not found
```

Is there a limitation that I am unaware of?

Comment: USB 2.0 vs 3.0 cable or port? Have you already reported this at some bug tracker?

Comment: cable, not port. where should I report it?

Comment: Either https://launchpad.net or the upstream developers of ADB (Google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADB server code (`system/core/adb/usb_linux.c`) is not looking for endpoint companion descriptors. It assumes bulk in and bulk out endpoint descriptors follow the interface descriptor. 
See diff for fixing

```
diff --git a/adb/usb_linux.c b/adb/usb_linux.c
index 7bf2057..52e6412 100644
--- a/adb/usb_linux.c
+++ b/adb/usb_linux.c
@@ -160,6 +160,7 @@ static void find_usb_device(const char *base,
             unsigned zero_mask = 0;
             unsigned vid, pid;
             size_t desclength;
+           int is_ss = 0; /* boolean */

             if(badname(de->d_name)) continue;
             snprintf(devname, sizeof devname, "%s/%s", busname, de->d_name);
@@ -195,6 +196,10 @@ static void find_usb_device(const char *base,
             vid = device->idVendor;
             pid = device->idProduct;
             DBGX("[ %s is V:%04x P:%04x ]\n", devname, vid, pid);
+           if (device->bcdUSB == 0x0300) {
+                    D("super speed device found: V:%04x P:%04x\n", vid, pid);
+                   is_ss = 1;
+           }

                 // should have config descriptor next
             config = (struct usb_config_descriptor *)bufptr;
@@ -237,6 +242,8 @@ static void find_usb_device(const char *base,
                             // looks like ADB...
                         ep1 = (struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *)bufptr;
                         bufptr += USB_DT_ENDPOINT_SIZE;
+                       if (is_ss)
+                               bufptr += 6; /* USB_DT_SS_EP_COMP_SIZE */
                         ep2 = (struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *)bufptr;
                         bufptr += USB_DT_ENDPOINT_SIZE;
```